# What's the end on 'print "%d" % (5)' called?

Tags: python, python-2.7, linguistics

A linguistic question I guess, but what's the (5) called in the code 
`print "%d" % (5)` ?

I call the `%d` an integer representation, but I'm not sure what to call the stuff it actually represents, regardless of it being a number, a variable, a calculation or *w/e*. 
Is it called an argument?

I'm wondering because I'm making comments for an assignment where I'm calculating stuff in the parenthesis instead of making a new variable, calculating the variable and inserting the variable like `x = 5;print "%d" % (x)`

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) describes it as *"values"*, or *"the argument"*, and the `%d` a *"conversion specification"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) calls it "values":

> If *format* requires a single argument, *values* may be a single non-tuple object.

The `%d` is called "conversion specifications". Each of them takes one or more "arguments" from the elements in "values".

`%d` takes one argument, `%*d` takes two, for example. All arguments make up "values".

That would mean `5` is the argument to `%d` while `(5)` is the "values" for the whole format.

Comment: *"So "argument" refers to the `%d`"* - no, that's the "conversion specification", the value (or tuple of values) is the argument.

Answer (score 0):

`(5)` is actually a very misleading thing: it looks like it is a tuple, but it is merely an integer with parens around it!

Either write

```
print "%d" % 5
```

or the right way to write a single-element tuple,

```
print "%d" % (5,)
```

Or you will have problems later when you have a case where it does matter (like when instead of `5`, you have a variable that may or may not be a tuple itself).

E.g.,

```
a = (2, 3)

print "%s" % a
```

raises TypeError, since `a` has two elements and there's only one `%`.

```
print "%s" % (a)
```

also raises TypeError, because it's the exact same thing, and

```
print "%s" % (a,)
```

actually prints the intended `"(2, 3)"`.